# Lower-dimensional Bands in Higher-dimensional Band Structure

Tags: conductors, electronic-band-theory, fermi-energy

This is (at least for me) an entirely hypothetical question. How would a lower-dimensional band within a higher-dimensional band structure affect the overall conductive properties of a material? To understand what exactly I mean, assume the band structure of the following Hamiltonian:

$ H(\vec{k}) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & h(\vec{k}) \\ h^*(\vec{k}) & 0 \end{pmatrix} + M\cdot\sigma_z $

with $h(\vec{k})=\sum_{j}\exp(i\vec{k}\vec{a}_j)~$, lattice vectors $\vec{a}_j$ and a mass term proportional to $M$ that will be set to $M=0.3$, here. E.g. for graphene, this results in a band structure like the following (in the figure, "a" is the lattice constant, the energy is in arbitrary units):

[image: Graphene band structure with non-trivial mass term]

Importantly, this band structure has a band gap of $2M$ around the Fermi energy. The material is therefore an insulator. Now let's add a third band to this, but this band will be discontinuous. For this, take the following Hamiltonian:

$H_r^\prime(\vec{k}) = E_0(1-\delta_{|\vec{k}|,r/a})$.

This one seems very unintuitive, but it becomes clear once there is a figure to it:

[image: Graphene band structure with discontinuous third band]

This figure shows the combined band structures of $H(\vec{k})$ and $H_{3}^\prime(\vec{k})$ with $E_0=4$. The new Hamiltonian $H_{3}^\prime(\vec{k})$ generates a single band that is localised at energy $E=4$ everywhere, except for when $|\vec{k}|=3/a$, i.e. when the reciprocal vector lies on a circle around the centre of the Brillouin zone. For values on this circle, the energy values are $E=0$ and form a ring between the former valence and conduction band.

One can easily make it so that the ring satisfies the periodicity of the first Brillouin zone by defining

$H_r^{\prime\prime}(\vec{k}) := \sum_\vec{G} H_r^\prime(\vec{k}-\vec{G})$,

where the sum goes over all (multiples of the) reciprocal lattice vectors $\vec{G}$. (Please pardon my sloppy notation here. This step is only for completeness and does not concern my primary question.)

My question now is:

**How does such a one-dimensional ring between the two-dimensional valence and conduction band affect the conductive properties of the material?**

Moreover, how would these properties change if the ring would reach into the next Brillouin zone? In that case, it would touch another ring, creating a shape that spans indefinitely across the reciprocal space.

One can extend this problem to lower dimensions as well. There, one would obtain a single point between two bands of an otherwise 2D band structure. In 3D, one would have a 2D band within a 3D band structure. Mathematically, these lower-dimensional bands are null sets within the higher dimensional band structures. So I'd assume that their contribution to the overall conductive properties would be small. But I have difficulties finding any sources on something like this. Nonetheless, I'm very interested in understanding this, simply to improve my personal understanding of conduction.

Comment: Do you have a physical model in mind behind this ring discontinuity in band structure?

Comment: It originates from a consideration about Floquet theory where one has replicas of the original bands. These replica bands can be associated (in some approximation) with a number of photons. A ($+1$)- and a ($-1$)-photon band can exhibit an avoided crossing, resulting in effective $0$-photon areas across the intersection. The association with photon numbers isn't entirely correct, and the replica bands exist beyond those intersections as well, but the idea of a band that only exists along these intersections is what made me wonder about how such a lower-dimensional band would behave.